# How to prevent TextBlock taking all the available space

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my problem. I've built the following `ListView`

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="messageList" BorderThickness="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Received.SenderId}" 
                                />
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Received.DeliverDate}" 
                               />
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Received.MsgText}"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">

                    </TextBlock>

                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Sent.SenderId}" 
                                />
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Sent.DeliverDate}" 
                                />
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Sent.MsgText}"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">

                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

For each element of `MySource` only 1 between Received and Sent will be not null. The `ListView`is working as i expect, placing the element on the left or the right of the screen, but the `TextBlock` that contain the `MsgText` get all the available space (so the whole row) if the message is too long. How can i limit it to stay only in one half of the parent Grid and make the text overflow eventually?

**EDIT**: I added an image showing my problem. The 4th message should overflow, but it doesn't

[image: this is how it looks]

Comment: set the horizontalAllignment property for it

Comment: @DenisSchaf already tried on the textblock. I setted it to stretch but it did nothing

Comment: try "left",  "right" or "center" as strech will make it take all the space available

Comment: it' din't worked either

Comment: Did you consider using a column definition for that grid?

Comment: You may get better answers if you demonstrate the problem better (more clear), see [mcve]. Show screenshot how is it now and another one, where you show how you want it to be instead.

Comment: Column are already defined with width 5* each. The problem, as far as i can tell, is that, when a grid column has no content inside, it doesn't reserve any space

Comment: @Sinatr added an image so you can understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me few minutes to produce [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but the missing part of the puzzle is this:

```
<Grid MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
```

That would limit maximum width of all `Grid`s (each item has one) and let wrapping happens. Otherwise `Grid` is [asking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout#measuring-and-arranging-children) for a width to fit whole item in one line and `ListView` is ok with it, but then you will see horizontal scrollbar (the most hated control by users including me).

---

MCVE:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Received { get; set; }
        public string Sent { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Received = "1111 111 11 111 11 1" },
            new Item { Received = "2222 2 22 2  2 222222222 2 222222 22222222 222222222222 2" },
            new Item { Sent = "333333333 3333333 333   33333 3  3 33 333333333 3333" },
            new Item { Received = "444444444444444 444 44444444444444 44  4 44444444444444444 4 4 4444444444 4 444   444444444444" },
        };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Received}"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Sent}"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your grid (and the width of the column) is calculated for each element of your list, so it takes the most space possible. I propose a backup solution, I did not find better but the result is there.

This is to place 2 ListView in 2 columns of a grid and then have the Received element in one and the Sent in the other.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="messageListReceived" BorderThickness="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Text="{Binding Received.SenderId}" 
                        />
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Text="{Binding Received.DeliverDate}" 
                        />
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Text="{Binding Received.MsgText}"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">

                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="messageListSent" BorderThickness="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Text="{Binding Sent.SenderId}" 
                        />
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Text="{Binding Sent.DeliverDate}" 
                        />
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Text="{Binding Sent.MsgText}"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">

                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your effort. Unfortunatly this was exactly my first implementation. The problem is that this create 2 separate control with 2 different scrollviewer. Since what i'm displaying won't probably fit the screen, i need to scroll the chat, but it's not acceptable to scroll only 1 half. That's why i implemented everything in a single listview